# Node.js + Express basic syntax explanation

Tags: node.js

I just started to see a beginner's tutorial on node.js. It uses the following:

```
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 80)
```

In the address bar it appears as `localhost/test.html` and not `localhost/public/test.html` - so in node.js you can control what's on the address bar regardless to the project structure, as it would've been in PHP?

Or `app.use` is only a one-time declaration, determining where the root is? such as `htdocs` or `/var/www/html`. Because you probably can't do both:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/folder'));
```

Comment: app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));... means you want to access the files inside the public folder...but in your case you need write app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'))....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `app.use` You're attaching middleware.

If You want to use middleware in all routing logic You do it like:

```
app.use(middlewareHere);
```

Or You can define exact routing prefix when that middleware will be used:

```
app.use('/someRouteHere', middlewareHere);
```

So for Your case by doing:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

You're telling to express to it like:

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

which means to call `express.static` middleware in all kinds of routings before processing next route handlers.

If You want to use it like: `localhost/public/test.html`

You've to attach middleware like this:

```
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

it's more secure that doing like:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
```

because by defining exact route You're isolating static file handling to exact folder and other internal files that may keep sensible data (passwords, creds) cannot be accessible by static handler.

But best practice is keeping static files in assets folder and handling index.html as root route:

```
app.use('/assets', express.static(__dirname + '/assets'));

const indexFile = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/assets/index.html');
app.all('/', (req, res) => res.status(200).send(indexFile);
```

P.S. I recommend You to read [official manual](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router) to understand routing logic.

UPDATE:

This part does not relate directly to Your question, it's for Your comment.

It's just an example. More detailed about how and why and etc read docs and google it. (:

Let's say You want to get data from database and inject that data to placeholders in `.html` files.

So it will be like this:

```
const ejs = require('ejs'); 
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', ejs.renderFile);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/assets'); // since You want to keep html and other static files together

app.use('/assets', express.static(__dirname + '/assets'));

app.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.session.userId;
  db.query(
    'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1',  
    [userId], 
    (error, rows) => {
      cons user = rows[0];
      res.render('profile', {user}); // passing user object to view
    });
});
```

And in Your `profile.html` :

```
<html>
</head>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
  Hello <b><%= user.username %></b>
</body>
</html>
```

Mini ejs tutorial about looping and etc in terms of php short open tags example:

```
<% let counter = 0; %>
<% while(counter < 100) { counter++; %>
<%= counter %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: I definitely need to read it because I still don't get some of the things you mentioned. So in node.js, when you say static files, you mostly (for beginners) mean plain `.html` - right? Then let's say I route to `index.html` as you said. and then I have another `profile.html` in assets, how do you insert server-side stuff to it as you would do with php? For example in `profile.html` I want to echo `Hello <username>`, when `<username>` is fetched from a database? I assume you don't do it directly on the `profile.html` or `server.js` because, `profile.html` is static?

Comment: @pileup added an example when You want render .html file as if it was view file

Comment: Thank you! I have the last question regarding your example: Is it the way you'd normally manipulate files with node.js? (Is this example the equivalent of PHP files manipulating, or you did it that way just because I ask, and you usually use a different way? If yes, I'd like just a direction on where to look, thanks again!). Because if I use node, I probably have to start manipulating HTML completely with node because I can't mix both PHP and node now

Comment: In my examples I'm not manipulating files (: I'm adding placeholders and pushing variables to replace that placeholders. Like if it was with: `Twig` for php. Watch this crash course: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gnsO8-xJ8rs he cowers all aspects in simple manner

Comment: But with PHP you can actually add html for example: `$counter = 0; while (condition) {echo "<p>Text #". $counter ."</p>"; $counter++;}` - what is this equivalent (I know I said the last question, but this is it, seriously! - ty for the link) (Or I should create a new separate question)

Comment: just replace `<?`, to `<%`, but better read ejs rendering engine markup. http://ejs.co/#docs   read from `Tags` part